# How to initialize a select tag with values from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, graphql

I'm iterating through some `items` picked from a GraphQl server. I have a `select` tag whose value I'm picking from `localStorage`, and then I'm passing the `items` as options.

it seems to work fine until I refresh the page, and instead of picking the initial value from
`localStorage`, it picks the first option of the `items` as the `value`.

I want my initial value to come from localStorage, not the `items` I'm iterating through.

Here is the select element

```
class Header extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currency: 'USD',
      cartItems: [],
      itemInCart: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(this.state.cartItems))
  }

  addToCart = (product) => {
    const alreadyInCart = this.state.cartItems.some(item => item.id === product.id)
    if( alreadyInCart ) {
      this.setState({ itemInCart: true })
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ itemInCart: false });
      }, 3000)
    } else {
      product.count = 1;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        cartItems: [...prevState.cartItems, product]
      }))
    }
  }

  removeFromCart = (id) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      cartItems: prevState.cartItems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    }))
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    localStorage.setItem('symbol', `${value}`)
    this.setState({ currency: value});
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    const { currency } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <nav>
          <div className="nav-ul">
            <Query query={GET_CATEGORIES}>
              { ({ loading, data }) => {
                if (loading) return null;
                return data.categories.map((category) => (
                  <Link to={`/${category.name}`} key={nanoid()} className="nav-li">{category.name.toUpperCase()}</Link>
                ));
              }}
            </Query>
          </div>
          <Link to='/'><img src={logo} alt="logo" /></Link>
          <div>
            {/* The issue is around here */}
            <select id="currency" onChange={this.onChange} value={localStorage.getItem('symbol')}> 
              <Query query={GET_CURRENCIES}>
                { ({ loading, data }) => {
                  if (loading) return null;
                  return data.currencies.map((currency) => (
                    <option
                      key={nanoid()}
                      value={currency.label}
                    >
                      {`${currency.symbol} ${currency.label}`}
                    </option>
                  ));
                }}
              </Query>
            </select>
            <Link to='/cart'><img src={cart} alt="cart" /></Link>
          </div>
        </nav>
        { this.state.itemInCart && <p>Item already in cart</p>}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Product homepage="all" currency={currency} addToCart={this.addToCart}/>} /> //the issue is here
          <Route path="/:category" element={<Product currency={currency} addToCart={this.addToCart}/>} />
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={ <ProductDetail currency={currency} addToCart={this.addToCart} />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={ <Cart cartItems={this.state.cartItems} /> }/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Here is the function adding the value to local storage

```
onChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    localStorage.setItem('symbol', `${value}`)
    this.setState({ currency: value});
  }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide minimum reproduction of problem, so community can help you.

Comment: @MohitSharma let me do that

Comment: I should also add that when I save (not refresh), it re-renders and gives me the correct value from localStorage

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce your code, but I would suggest you a slightly different approach that might be helpful.

I would provide the **symbol** as a stateful variable that is initialized according to the value stored inside the localStorage or a default one.

```js
const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState(localStorage.getItem('symbol') ?? "default");
```

Then, I would integrate a side effect using the **useEffect** hook (or the **componentDidUpdate** method, if you are using classes) that triggers an action everytime the content of the symbol variable changes

```js
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('symbol', symbol);
}, [symbol]); // runs on mounting and on each symbol update
```

Then, the `onChange()` function would be responsible of triggering setSymbol only

```js
const onChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setSymbol(value);
    // ...
}
```

You are, then, able to treat the symbol as a stateful variable like the other ones knowing that, everytime it changes, it will be also stored inside localStorage and that everytime the component is initialized the value from the localStorage will be read initially.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's an interview question, and they require that we use classes only.  I also tried doing something similar with componentDidMount but with no luck. I initialized the state but for some reason, it wasn't being read. It went straight to the first value picked from server.